# Problem adding a new column with a foreign key in an Alembic migration with sqlalchemy

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm having some problems with a db migration when trying to add a new column with a foreign key constraint. Here is the model (the new column is **reference_oil** and I've also added the **oil_ingredient** relation):

```
class UserProfileInfo(DECLARATIVE_BASE):
    __tablename__ = 'userProfileInfo'
    __table_args__ = ({'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB', 'mysql_charset': 'utf8'})

    id = Column(  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        "userId", INTEGER, ForeignKey("user.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), primary_key=True, nullable=False, index=True
    )
    name = Column(TEXT, nullable=True)
    surname = Column(TEXT, nullable=True)
    sex = Column(SMALLINT, nullable=True)
    lifestyle = Column(TEXT, nullable=True)
    weight = Column(FLOAT, nullable=True)
    height = Column(FLOAT, nullable=True)
    birth = Column(DATE, nullable=True)
    timezone = Column(TEXT, nullable=True, default="CET")
    default_portion_size = Column(TEXT, nullable=True)
    default_salt_level = Column(TEXT, nullable=True)
    default_sugar_level = Column(TEXT, nullable=True)

    reference_oil = Column(INTEGER, ForeignKey("ingredient.id", ondelete="SET NULL"), index=True, nullable=True)

    user = relationship("User", foreign_keys=[id], backref="userprofileinfo")
    oil_ingredient = relationship("Ingredient", foreign_keys=[reference_oil], backref="userProfileInfo")
```

Here is the model of the referenced table:

```
class Ingredient(DECLARATIVE_BASE):
    __tablename__ = 'ingredient'
    __table_args__ = ({'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB', 'mysql_charset': 'utf8'})

    id = Column(INTEGER, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True, nullable=False)  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
    name = Column(sa.TEXT, nullable=False)
    category = Column(sa.VARCHAR(30), nullable=True)
    nutrition = Column(sa.TEXT, nullable=True)
    avgQuantity = Column(sa.FLOAT, nullable=False)
```

And this is the migration code:

```
def upgrade():
    op.add_column('userProfileInfo', sa.Column('reference_oil', sa.INTEGER, nullable=True, index=True))
    op.create_foreign_key(None, 'userProfileInfo', 'ingredient', ['reference_oil'], ['id'], ondelete='SET NULL')
    dh.db_session.commit()
```

I've also tried this way, which results in the same error:

```
def upgrade():
    op.add_column('userProfileInfo',
                  Column('reference_oil', INTEGER, ForeignKey('ingredient.id'))
                  )
    dh.db_session.commit()
```

Running the migration results in the following error:

```
  File "/code/alembic/versions/a49125f843c9_add_user_oil_columns_30_05_2022.py", line 33, in upgrade
    op.create_foreign_key(None, 'userProfileInfo', 'ingredient', ['reference_oil'], ['id'], ondelete='SET NULL')
  File "<string>", line 8, in create_foreign_key
  File "<string>", line 3, in create_foreign_key
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/operations/ops.py", line 643, in create_foreign_key
    return operations.invoke(op)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/operations/base.py", line 373, in invoke
    return fn(self, operation)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/operations/toimpl.py", line 152, in create_constraint
    operation.to_constraint(operations.migration_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/ddl/impl.py", line 245, in add_constraint
    self._exec(schema.AddConstraint(const))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/ddl/impl.py", line 141, in _exec
    return conn.execute(construct, *multiparams, **params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1306, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params, _EMPTY_EXECUTION_OPTS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 81, in _execute_on_connection
    self, multiparams, params, execution_options
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1404, in _execute_ddl
    compiled,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1863, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2044, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1820, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 315, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 239, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1050, "Table './qaav729/userprofileinfo' already exists")
[SQL: ALTER TABLE `userProfileInfo` ADD FOREIGN KEY(reference_oil) REFERENCES ingredient (id) ON DELETE SET NULL]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
ERROR: 1
```

Any ideas what may be the problem? Thanks!

**Update**:
We're now trying to store all the data in the table in a variable, drop the table and recreate it again, but without success. It seems retrieving the information works fine, dropping the table also works but then the sqlalchemy create table method fails:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 239, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError) (1146, "Table 'qaav729.userprofileinfo' doesn't exist")
[SQL:
CREATE TABLE `userProfileInfo` (
    `userId` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name TEXT,
    surname TEXT,
    sex SMALLINT,
    lifestyle TEXT,
    weight FLOAT,
    height FLOAT,
    birth DATE,
    timezone TEXT,
    default_portion_size TEXT,
    default_salt_level TEXT,
    default_sugar_level TEXT,
    default_oil_level TEXT,
    reference_oil INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (`userId`),
    FOREIGN KEY(`userId`) REFERENCES user (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(reference_oil) REFERENCES ingredient (id) ON DELETE SET NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8

]
```

Could there be an issue with the table name? After dropping the table trying to recreate it results in the above error, but recreating it with a different name works just fine.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. BTW, is `qaav729` the name of the database?

Comment: Also, what version of MySQL are you using? I tested against version 8.0.21.

Comment: Thanks @GordThompson, at the moment I think it may be that the table is corrupted in some way... yes qaav729 is the name of the database and to be honest I'm not quite sure what version of MySQL we're running. I'm looking into rebuilding the table at the moment to see if that will solve it.

Comment: Okay, please let us know how it goes. For future reference, you can use `select version()`.

Comment: Dropping the table then recreating is also giving me the same error... After the table is dropped the create_table command gives the following error:
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError) (1146, "Table 'qaav729.userprofileinfo' doesn't exist")

Comment: So what does `select version()` say?

Comment: @GordThompson 5.7.37
At the moment I think it's something to do with the table name... Creating a table with the same name (after dropping it) results in the last error I posted and if I change the name it works just fine

Comment: Still unable to reproduce with MySQL 5.7.32. My test code is [here](https://github.com/gordthompson/alembic_demo/tree/so72446074). FWIW, I've seen other cases where mixed-case table names on MySQL have confused Alembic.

Comment: Thanks for your help @GordThompson, we've decided it's ok to rename the table for now and move on.